# What sidequests are achieveable during Wicked Eyes, Wicked Hearts if you want the public truce?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Basically what the title says - I know there's a Halla statue limit, and I know going in what kind of ending I'd like to achieve, but I'm not sure what sidequests this ending will allow me to do - does anyone out there know?